# SAS, combine strings

Tags: sas

I have a dataset test1, I want to generate a key which is the combination of any of the specified variables. For example, the key in ideal_1, or the key in ideal_2. I need to write a macro for this, but the challenges for me is that the number of the vars are not fixed, as you can see in ideal1, it is the combination of 2, and in ideal3 it is the combination of 3.

```
data test1;
input var1$ var2$ var3$ var4$ var5$ var6$;
datalines;

1 a  a b e
2 a  f b e
3 a  a a a
1 b  a a a
2 a  f b e

;
run;

data ideal_1;
 set test1;
 key=strip(var1)||strip(var2);
run;

data ideal_2;
 set test1;
 key=strip(var1)||strip(var2)||strip(var5);
run;
```

Comment: What is the question?  If you use functions and variable lists then it is pretty simple to make code that is independent of the number of variables in the list.  `key=cats(of var1 var2 var5)`

Comment: the number of var is not specific. For example, some people will choose to combine 2 var (var 1 & var 2), other people will combine (var 1, var3 & var5). I don't know their choice ahead of time, so I will write this as a macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a variable list.  You could store the list into a macro variable to make it easier to edit.

```
%let keylist=var1 var2 var5 ;
```

Then you can use the macro variable where ever you need it.

```
data ideal_2;
  set test1;
  key=cats(of &keylist);
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the variables have a naming convention as in your example you can use something like the following, which uses the colon operator to concatenate all of the variables that start with the prefix VAR.

```
key = catt(of var:);
```